# Parallel scan in shared memory in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I have a problem where each thread block (1 dimension) has to run a scan on an array inside shared memory with several other tasks. The array have at most 1024 elements.

Is there any good library which supports this type of operation?

I checked Thrust and CudPP but both of them are working only when the data is initially in global memory which is not what I want because I don't want to start a new kernel for each small segment and copying back the data to the global memory because it has quite a big overhead.

If there is no public library which support this type of operations, than what do you suggest if I want to write this operation only once and use it in several different problems?

My first idea is to write a simple device function what runs the scan operation, but is it possible to accessing shared memory and doing `__syncthreads()` operations from a device function which is not the kernel function?

My other idea is to write the whole function in a macro, and then it would work because the preprocessor copies the code to the kernel code but writing such a complex macro isn't the best way to use macros.

PS.: I have streaming multiprocessor version 2.1, so I can't start a new kernel from another (no CUDA Dynamic Parallelism).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any good library which support this type of operation?
>
> If there is no public library which support this type of operations, than what do you suggest if I want to write this operation only once and use it in several different problems?

There is a library named CUB -  that stands for CUDA UnBound. You find it [here](http://nvlabs.github.com/cub/). It provides a scan functionality.
If you want to write something similar yourself, CUB could be helpful to see how it is done.

> My first idea is to write a simple host function what runs the scan opertaion, but is it possible to accessing shared memory and doing __syncthreads() operations from a device function which is not the kernel function?

I am not sure what you mean by "host function what runs the scan opertaion".
The only thing you can do from host code is to start a kernel and memory copies. Unless the device function is called from the block that owns the shared memory in question, the answer is no.
Shared memory is allocated per block and is accessible only from inside the block.

Comment: Thanks fort the answer, CUB is exactly look likes what I am looking for. I wanted to write a device function not a host one. I just miss write it.